# How to fix "OSError: cannot open profile file" using Pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am working on a small script, which is going to open external .PSD and do some logging from it.

I am using psd_tools to work with PSD. It uses PIL.

Everything works fine until I bundle it into .EXE with pyinstaller.
Then it throws OSError: cannot open profile file.

I cant figure out whether the problem is in PIL, psd_tools or pyinstaller(Well, I am pretty newbie though).

Here is the code:

```
from psd_tools import *

psd = PSDImage.load('C:\python3\layers.psd')

print('success')
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "layers_tr.py", line 1, in <module>
    from psd_tools import *
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\psd_tools\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\psd_tools\user_api\psd_image.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\psd_tools\user_api\pil_support.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\psd_tools\icc_profiles\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "site-packages\PIL\ImageCms.py", line 162, in __init__
OSError: cannot open profile file
[12424] Failed to execute script layers_tr
```

Any help pls

Comment: I have no problems with freeze apps for `psd_tools` and you don't need to do any additional work. Have you tried using a `virtualenv` with lastest Pyinstaller? I also saw that currently, my `psd_tools` file structure is a little difference with what you currently have. Maybe updating it with `pip install -U psd_tools` fix the problem.

Comment: You were right, updating `psd_tools` solved the problem. It seems I somehow got the outdated version, though I have installed it yesterday. It depricated `.load()` method I was using, and now I gonna use `.open()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updaing `psd_tools` with
    `pip install -U psd_tools`
solved the problem. Big Thanks to M. R.